# Borrow checker problems with serde-reflection

Tags: templates, types, rust, traits, serde

I'm trying to use `serde-reflection` to create a JSON structure explaining the struct structure in order to transfer and receive structs as JavaScript an `ArrayBuffer` and then de-serialize that into a JavaScript Object in the browser.

I want a way to "register" the structs I'm interested in and then keeping track of all those registered types so that they can be returned from a web server.

```rust
extern crate serde_json;
use serde_json::json;

use serde_reflection::{Samples, Tracer, TracerConfig};

pub struct MessageRegistry {
    tracer: Tracer,
    samples: Samples
}

impl MessageRegistry {
    pub fn new() -> MessageRegistry {
        MessageRegistry {
            tracer: Tracer::new(TracerConfig::default()),
            samples: Samples::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn add_type<T>(&mut self) {
        self.tracer.trace_type::<T>(&self.samples).unwrap();
                  //^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `T`
    }

    pub fn to_json_string(&mut self) -> String {
        let registry = self.tracer.registry().unwrap();
        serde_json::to_string(&registry).unwrap()
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on using the `tracer.trace_type::<T>(&self.samples)` line. If I try it out with `pub fn add<'de, T: serde::Deserialize<'de>>(&mut self) {` instead I get into problems with the lifetime instead:

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
expected `serde::Deserialize<'_>`
   found `serde::Deserialize<'de>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile error tells you how to fix the error, just add a `Deserialize` bound to the generic parameter `T`. Since the borrow comes from `&self.samples` then `Deserialize` must also be tied to `self` somehow, which we can specify with the generic parameter `'a`:

```rust
use serde::de::Deserialize;
use serde_reflection::{Registry, Samples, Tracer, TracerConfig};

pub struct MessageRegistry {
    tracer: Option<Tracer>,
    samples: Samples,
    registry: Option<Registry>,
}

impl MessageRegistry {
    pub fn new() -> MessageRegistry {
        MessageRegistry {
            tracer: Some(Tracer::new(TracerConfig::default())),
            samples: Samples::new(),
            registry: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn add_type<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>(&'a mut self) {
        self.tracer.as_mut().unwrap().trace_type::<T>(&self.samples).unwrap();
    }

    pub fn to_json_string(&mut self) -> String {
        self.registry = self.tracer.take().unwrap().registry().ok();
        serde_json::to_string(self.registry.as_ref().unwrap()).unwrap()
    }
}
```

Note: `tracer.registry()` consumes the `tracer` so I had to wrap it in an `Option`. Also added a `Registry` field wrapped in the object that represents the results of the consumed `tracer`.

Comment: Thank you so much! The `&'a mut self` was all I needed, now it works as intended! :)